# Alternatives to FlowPlayer

Tags: library, javascript, video, streaming, html

Looking for alternatives to [FlowPlayer](https://flowplayer.org/)–a platform for streaming/embedding videos on websites.

- it should support the common video formats (mp4 etc.)
- offer hosting
- uploading private videos
- good CDN (fast streaming)
- nice JavaScript API
- fast in terms of performance
- good device support